# Texture Mapped Incorrect on Some of the Faces

Tags: texturing, faces

### Question

After I mapped the texture of an object, some of the faces seem that does not have a correct texture mapping like the following image. I have tried to recalculate the normals but it does not help. Why? How to fix it?

[image]

---

### Study

When I select a face with texture mapped correctly, the area with texture background also displayed in the **UV/Image Editor**.

[image] [image]

While when I select the face with texture mapped incorrectly, the **UV/Image Editor** cannot shows me the texture background.

[image] [image]

Comment: The reason might be what Mr Zak said or you can have different material on those faces. If the first is true, Pin UV map and re-unwrap weird faces.If the second, change material to one, shared by other faces.

Comment: @MrZak - Yes, I have tried to recreate the faces but it does not help. How to know what render engine I am using?

Comment: After recreating those faces did you refresh unwrap ? If not then it's most possibly the reason. If yes then as Mzidare wrote you might not assign those faces to the material which uses texture. Look up in the [Info editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/info/introduction.html) to see which render engine is; although I think now it's not that important in this case as it doesn't really change anything regarding to texture showing.

Comment: @MrZak - How to refresh unwrap?

Comment: Refresing unwrap is done by reunwrapping once again; if parts of old UV map should be preserved, select them and pin, then re-unwrap. From what is shown on your last screenshot it looks like your UV map is OK, it's just that those faces aren't assigned to the desired texture. Try selecting all and choosing that texture in the UV/Image editor once more (still I guess you use BI).